# Fix bad mud job after knock down and ceiling paint applied

Tags: mudding

I messed up! We had a large hole about 3x4 feet we filled after removing some old tube lights. After mudding, I assumed I would not need to feather out as much because the knock down would cover it.  In my haste, I continued to apply primer and ceiling paint. Big mistake... its an eye sore! Do i need to scrape it all off? If so, how far out should i scrape it off? Can I just mud and feather over the current texture and do I need to prime? Im very frustrated with myself for not slowing down and need advice on how to do this the easiest yet best way possible. Thank you!! [image: textured ceiling after bad mud job]

Comment: sand the eyesore are down till it is flat, then reapply

Comment: I'm assuming I'll need to feather more than I did initially, should I sand down the knock down all around about maybe a foot on each side?